# URL rewriting fails because of url encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently implemented versioning on my API project. Now URLs of my api will have to be prefixed by the sequence `/v1/` (As I'm currently on v1)

I don't want to break old calls, so to ensure transparent compatibility, I want to rewrite the old urls.

Url like `/events/9999/attendees` should be redirected to `/v1/events/9999/attendees`

I set this up with my rails routes config file `routes.rb` with the following code :

```
match "*path", :to => redirect("/#{API_CONFIG['current_version']}/%{path}"),
:constraints => lambda { |request| true }
```

The issue I'm facing now is that the final rewritten route seems to be url-encoded ... (or something) *Actually, that's the* `%{path}` *that seems to be broken*. Then :

`/events/9999/attendees` is redirected to `/v1/events%2F9999%2Fattendees`

What am I doing wrong ?

Many thanks

Comment: what about `url_encode(path)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass a block to `redirect` to specify the correct url

```
match "*path", :to => redirect {|params, request| "/v1/#{params[:path]}"}, :constraints => lambda { |request| true }
```