# Redirecting a path to a new domain in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

I want to redirect requests for a bunch of files/folders in a directory on one site to a directory (and then identical path) on a new site.

In my Rails routes.rb I have:

```
match '/uploads/*path', :to => redirect{|params, request| "http://othersite.com/uploads/#{params[:path]}"}
```

which I've got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338816/url-rewriting-fails-because-of-url-encoding).

It almost works, except this URL:

```
http://currentsite.com/uploads/some/directories/filename.pdf
```

redirects to:

```
http://othersite.com/uploads/some/directories/filename
```

I can't work out why the file extension is missing.

(I would also add something like `constraints: {:path => /[\w\-_\/]+(\.[a-z]+)?/}` to the end to ensure the path is vaguely valid, but I've left that off while trying to fix this issue.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to include the request format:

```
match '/uploads/*path', :to => redirect{|params, request| "http://othersite.com/uploads/#{params[:path]}#{ '.'+params[:format] if params[:format].present? }"}
```

... this is the portion of the URI we think of as the file extension (ie: `.pdf` in your example).

Though, it may be more elegant to just use the full incoming request path (via `request.full_path`, which has the URI path and all query params):

```
match '/uploads/*path', :to => redirect{|params, request| "http://othersite.com/uploads/#{ request.fullpath }" }
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, and a very quick answer! (8 minutes until I can mark it as correct, but I will do so later.)

Comment: Cheers!  I added a simpler solution that may work better, too.